# How to add initial data in indexeddb only once

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am creating an indexeddb, and have several stores in it. 
Have some data that has to be initially added when stores are created.

I have function where I create database and stores:

```js
function db_init(){
    var request = indexedDB.open("db", "1.0");

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(){
        var db = request.result;
        //store 1
        db.createObjectStore("store1", {keypath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
        //add initial datas;

        //store2
        db.createObjectStore("store2", {keypath: "id", autoIncrement: true});

        //...
        //store 3

        // init necessary databases

        db_populate();
    } 

    request.onsuccess = function (){
        db = request.result;
        populate:db();
    }     
}
```

And inside db_populate function have 4 other functions where I am populating datastores:

```
 function db_populate() {

    init_store1();
    init_store2();
    //...

     console.log("db populated with data");
 }
```

Each init_score populates stores with transactions like below:

```
 var tx = db.transaction("store1", "readwrite");
 var store = tx.objectStore("store1");
```

Now, I have a problem. Every time I open or refresh the page, the initial data are duplicated. There are added over again.

When I add db_populate at the end of `onupgradeneeded` function, I get an error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
```

on line:

```
  var tx = db.transaction ("store1", "readwrite");
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create data stores with its initial data once and that is it.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's due to the fact that you can't insert data during a upgrade needed event. What you need to do instead is close the connection after the upgrade and reopen it again for the data insert.

The flow should be something like this:

```js
function db_init() {
  var request = indexedDB.open("db");
  var dbShouldInit = false;
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    dbShouldInit = true;
    //store 1
    db.createObjectStore("store1", {
      keypath: "id",
      autoIncrement: true
    });
    //add initial datas;

    //store2
    db.createObjectStore("store2", {
      keypath: "id",
      autoIncrement: true
    });

  }
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    e.target.result.close();
    if(dbShouldInit)//executes only if DB init happened
      db_populate(); //close the db first and then call init
  }

}

function db_populate() {
  init_store1(init_store2); //pass init 2 as callback 
}

function init_store1(callback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open("db");
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("store1", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("store1");

    //init code here

    tx.oncomplete = function(e) {
      callback(); //here call the init for second function
    };
  }
}

function init_store2() {
  var request = indexedDB.open("db");
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("store2", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("store2");

    //init code here

    tx.oncomplete = function(e) {
      //here the app can continue
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit weird though, but what if I add data right after when I create stores? At least in the example 1 of http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#range-concept they have did it.

Comment: And what if I have more than 2 init functions? How can I add callbacks?

Comment: you pass array of functions, and execute all of them

Comment: @user3185491 did this answer helped you with your issue?

Comment: Nope, I have added functions into the array as callback to the first init_store, it does not see the db variable anymore.

Comment: all init functions should be the same, open db store items if you want them to be independent, do not use the open db only in one of them if you don't know the order of execution

Comment: so I should open database for all of init functions? And what do you mean "all init functions should be the same"?

Comment: May I know why it will add only once? Every time one reopens or refreshes, the function populate() is called, so it will add data to DB, is not true?

Comment: I added a flag which checks that, please see the code updates. What you need to check is if upgrade needed event happen, then insert the records, if no then app can continue

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function () {
  //indexedDB.deleteDatabase("store");
  var openDB = indexedDB.open("store", 1); 
  openDB.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    var db = openDB.result;
    var store;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("example")) {
      store = db.createObjectStore("example", {keyPath: "some"});
      store.put({some: "initData"});
    }
  };
  openDB.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var rqst = db.transaction("example", "readonly")
                 .objectStore("example")
                 .get("initData");
    rqst.onsuccess = function (e) {
      console.log(rqst.result);
    };
  };
})();
```